# Garage Band and Access Control

Tags: macos, acl, garageband

The things garage band writes are, in fact, directories.

Changing their access from the 'Get Info' menu changes the directory but not the files therein. I ended up using good old chmod to patch things up.

Is there some Finder-related recipe I can give the non-chmod-qualified user to make garage band artifacts accessible?

Comment: FWIW, the files saved are termed Bundles in Mac OS X if it helps your searching.